# Could the smooth 4 dimensional poincare conjecture be independent of ZFC?

Tags: logic, set-theory, smooth-manifolds, conjectures

The Smooth 4-dimensional Poincare conjecture ($S4PC$) states that any closed smooth 4-dimensional manifold which is homeomorphic to $S^4$ will be diffeomorphic to $S^4$.

My question is wether this statement could in principle be independent of the usual ZFC set theory, just like the continuum hypothesis.

The same question has been asked for the Goldbach conjecture (In Peano arithmetic) and the Riemann hypothesis (In ZFC), where the answer was (If I understood correctly): It is in both cases possible that they are independent of Peano arithmetic/ZFC, but in that case they would both be true in the standard models of Peano arithmetic/ZFC. Is the same thing true for $S4PC$?

I would guess that if we could translate $S4PC$ into a statement involving natural numbers then it's the same as for the Riemann hypothesis. But I do not know if that is possible. Maybe someone does?

Comment: I am not very firm with this conjecture. Goldbach conjecture and Riemann hypothesis are in fact examples , where a proof of independence of each of those cojectures (in PA or ZFC) would actually show that the corresponding conjecture is true. Collatz does NOT have this property : It is not clear that we can prove in ZFC that a possible divergent trajectory is actually divergent.

Comment: I think that every famous open conjecture could be unprovable in ZFC (even if it is true). I see no way to rule this out.

Comment: @Peter Is the same true for any unknown statement in mathematics then? Is there no sufficient condition on statements which guarantees that they are not independent of ZFC?

Comment: There are examples as the axiom of choice and the continuum hypothesis. Turing has however shown that there is no general method to predict whether some statement is provable. Nevertheless , ZFC is very powerful and it is expected that it can prove all true statements that are not artificial (that is designed explicitely for the purpose of independence) and therefore it is assumed ZFC can prove most of the famous open conjectures.

Comment: If a statement is however provable (assuming it is true) it is hard to imagine that we can predict this. I am not aware of such an example.

Comment: @Peter As a mathematician could I say: I am always working within the model of ZFC coming from the Van Neumann universe, therefore every mathematical statement is either true or false including the $S4PC$? Since I would like the law of the excluded middle to hold for conjectures and statement I care about...